# Embed Issue: "RichEmbed field values may not be empty."

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Ayo! I'm having issues with outputting an embed. The only issue that puzzles me is I don't have a field without anything and it goes through and sends it in Discord and THEN errors out.

It does the same thing when I'm detecting edits, this code is within my `bot.on("message", async message => {})`. Maybe that's the issue but I don't see why and where I would put it if else.

```
//-- Logging Deleted Messages --\\
bot.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
  let deletionEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription(" Deleted Message ")
    .setColor("#e56b00")
    .addField("User:", `${message.author}`)
    .addField("Message:", `${messageDelete}`);

  let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "server-log");
  if (!logchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find a logging channel!");

  logchannel.send(deletionEmbed);
});
```

This is the error message:

```
if (!/\S/.test(value)) throw new RangeError('RichEmbed field values may not be empty.');

RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

Answer (score 2):

The most important issue first: you have the `messageDelete` event handler inside your `message` event. That will make a new event listener for each message that your bot receives: it'll either crash your bot because of memory issues or spam like crazy.

You need to use this outside of your `message` event:

```js
bot.on("messageDelete", (oldMessage, newMessage) => {...});
```

Inside that handler, use these:

```
.addField("User:", `${newMessage.author.tag}`)
.addField("Message:", `${oldMessage.content}`);
```

Comment: If I use newMessage.author, it replies that there is no author. If I do oldMessage it does the same error I had before.

Comment: See you sure that you changed the client.on line

Comment: Yeah, I changed it. Having "newMessage" as the author errors out though & "oldMessage" as a replacement gives me the same error I had before.

Comment: Try `newMessage.author.tag`